# VBA Vlookup where Lookup_value column number is specifies

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm currently writing VBA code which includes a Vlookup. The code I have at the moment is this:

**ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'[Equities EMIR New.xlsx]Valuation Summary'!R2C4:R100C5,1,FALSE)"**

The problem I have is that the column that the Vlookup will be in a cell in a newly inserted column each time it is run. Therefore having RC[-7] for the lookup value won't work once the macro has been run more than once.

The lookup value will remain in the same cell (A3), however when I try and replace RC[-7] with A3, I get a #NAME? error.

I've been searching for days and I can't find a solution to this, is anyone able to assist?

Thanks.

Comment: convert the whole formula to use just the .Formula property not the .FormulaR1C1 property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Use R3C1 (Row 3, Column 1) - it's the absolute reference to cell A3 in R1C1 format.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ "=VLOOKUP(R3C1,'[Equities EMIRNew.xlsx]Valuation Summary'!R2C4:R100C5,1,FALSE)"
```

Remember in VBA that when using .FormulaR1C1 to use R1C1 formats for your references.

Answer (score 0):

there is a quick and dirty solution to your problem. 
The idea is that FormulaR1C1 expects a string, thus you should indent every time l_counter by -1.

```
Public Sub vlookup()

Dim l_counter As Long: l_counter = 7
'your loops here
    l_counter = l_counter - 1
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & l_counter & "],'[Equities EMIR New.xlsx]Valuation Summary'!R2C4:R100C5,1,FALSE)"
 'your loops here
 End Sub
```